# Permutate column values between group levels

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, slice

I have a dataframe

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 feat1 feat2
1 a x class1 class2
1 a y class1 class2
1 b x class2 class1
1 b y class2 class1
1 b z class2 class1
1 c x class1 class1
2 a x class1 class2
2 a y class1 class2
2 b x class2 class1
2 b y class2 class1
2 b z class2 class1
2 c x class1 class1
```

grouped by ID1, ID2, and ID3

I want to randomly reshuffle the feat1 and feat2 values (class1 or class2) between groups levels (this is, between a, b, and c), without replacement.
So that, a random output could be:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 feat1 feat2
1 a x class2 class1
1 a y class2 class1
1 b x class1 class1
1 b y class1 class1
1 b z class1 class1
1 c x class1 class2
2 a x class2 class1
2 a y class2 class1
2 b x class1 class1
2 b y class1 class1
2 b z class1 class1
2 c x class1 class2
```

In this random shuffling, 'a' takes feature values from 'b' ; 'b' takes them from 'c' ; and 'c' from 'a'

My code is

```
my_df_reshuffled = my_df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2, ID3) %>%
  slice(sample(1:n()))
```

But it does not shuffle values between groups, just changes the order of group levels while keeping the feat1 and feat2 values for each group equal.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think this might help you

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), ID2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "c"), ID3 = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "y", 
"x", "y", "z", "x"), feat1 = c("class1", "class1", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class1"), feat2 = c("class2", "class2", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class2", "class2", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID1) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("feat"),
                .fns = function(x)sample(x,length(x))))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   ID1 [2]
     ID1 ID2   ID3   feat1  feat2 
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
 1     1 a     x     class2 class1
 2     1 a     y     class2 class1
 3     1 b     x     class2 class2
 4     1 b     y     class1 class1
 5     1 b     z     class1 class1
 6     1 c     x     class1 class2
 7     2 a     x     class1 class1
 8     2 a     y     class1 class2
 9     2 b     x     class2 class1
10     2 b     y     class1 class2
11     2 b     z     class2 class1
12     2 c     x     class2 class1
```